# How to best position R Plotly annotation relative to legend

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I'm wondering if there's a 'best' way to define the position of an annotation such that it doesn't overlap with existing legend text.  Below is some sample code that generates 2 charts: 1 with a legend that only takes up one line and the second with a legend that take up 2 lines due to the length of the text.  I can easily define the position of an annotation such that it works for the first chart, but how would I programmatically define the position of the annotation "if the legend takes up 2 lines instead of just one"?  Is there a way to "get" the attributes of the existing legend so I can write an if statement based on the existing positioning or size of the legend?  Or is there a way I can define the yanchor of the annotation to be attached to the bottom of the legend?  Thanks!

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

pnames1 <- paste0("Short Name ", 1:4)
pnames2 <- paste0("A Really Really Long Legend Name ", 1:4)

fn_makeChart <- function(pnames){
  p <- plot_ly(height = 400, width = 800)
  for (n in 1:length(pnames)){
    p <- p %>%
      add_trace(x = 1:5,
                y = runif(5,0,10),
                name = pnames[n],
                color = pnames[n],
                type = 'scatter',
                mode = 'lines')
  }
  p <- p %>% 
    layout(legend = list(orientation = "h",
                         xanchor = "center",
                         x = 0.5, y = -0.1),
           showlegend = T) 
  p
}

anno <- list(x = 0.5, y = -0.23,
             xref = 'paper', yref = 'paper',
             text = 'My Annotation',
             xanchor = 'center', showarrow = F)

#the annotation looks fine on this chart:
fn_makeChart(pnames1) %>% layout(annotations = list(anno))

#but it overlaps the legend on this chart:
fn_makeChart(pnames2) %>% layout(annotations = list(anno))
```

[image]
[image]